# Is there any way to get response from server without cron in php?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want to run the script which will scan the database and do the operation automatically but without using cron. I'm using PHP as a programming language and MySQL as a DBMS. Here I have mentioned quick idea about the functionality I'm trying to develop

I have a module where I need to notify user on dynamic time with the duration of 24 hrs. That is user is posting one post and if he's not getting any response within 24 hrs then he will get notified automatically. So, if one user has posted on 8:30 PM then he'll get notification on second day at the same time. If second user has posted on 7:30 PM then he'll get notification on second day at 7:30 PM.

Now, first thought would come about setting cron as ideally there should sort of scheduler which run the script as per the schedule. In that case we need to schedule particular interval to run the script automatically, but here I won't have any fix time of interval. I know that we can do it by setting cron in minutes too however I don't find that option feasible to let server run the script on every 5-10 mins. So, I have decided to find an alternate(if possible) and thought whether there is any technique in PHP or server where the script will automatically run, scan the DB, fetch the time and if it reached at the 24 hrs then send the notification.

I got the suggestion of using socket as well from one of my colleague however that too I don't find useful

Comment: `feasible to let server run the script on every 5-10 mins` Why? If this script does only check and notify?

Answer (score 3):

What you want, and are descibing, *is* a cronjob.

> "but here I won't have any fix time of interval"

Do you mean you can't get something like "I want *this* user to get a notification, at 24hours from now, but it doesn't work like this"?
If thats the case, then it's a logic problem, which can be solved with something like:

```
$users2notify = getUsersWithAction24hoursAgo();
notifyUsers( $users2notify ); // only notify actual needed users
```

If you can't have cronjobs because of technical limitation, I recommend switching hosting. There really isn't a proper alternative to cronjobs, because cronjobs do their job really well.

*PS: Your friends socket suggestion, ignore it as it just shifts the problem to Javascript.*

Answer (score 0):

Using `cron` is the simplest and most PHP-ish solution but if you really hate `cron` you can start a `nodejs` application, that will delay a request with 24 hours: you send a request to `http://localhost:5000/delay?replayTo=http://localhost:80/che‌​ckUser?id=$idOfUserT‌​oCheck` and nodejs will make a get request after 24h; you will have to develop the nodejs application but it is not that complicated.

In this example, 5000 is the port that the nodejs application will listen; it can be any unused port.